# How to get the root node of an xml file in Python?

Tags: python, xml

Basically I am using:

from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

```
path = 'C:\cool.xml'
et = ET.parse ( path )
```

But I am not sure how to get the root from et?

Answer (score 10):

You probably want:

```
et.getroot()
```

Have a look at the official docs for ElementTree from the [effbot site](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm). Note that Python 2.5 (the first version of Python to include ElementTree out of the box) uses ElementTree 1.2, not the more recent 1.3. There aren't many differences, but just FYI in case.

Answer (score 4):

```
root = et.getroot()
```

I would recommend using lxml.etree instead of xml.etree.ElementTree, as lxml is faster and the interface is the same.

Comment: There is no syntactical difference?

Answer (score 2):

```
root = et.getroot()
```